# Right-click only to select a node in VirtualTreeView?

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I need to select a node of virtualstringtree by only a right click, and left click should not select the node. But I could not find a solution. Turning selection on, will also allow to left click and select a node.
Is this possible with the virtualstringtree?

Answer (score 0):

To enable select on `right-click` set `toRightClickSelect` in `SelectionOptions`:

```
VST1.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions := VST1.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions + [toRightClickSelect];
```

To prevent selection on mouse `left-click`, one option is to use `Abort` in `OnMouseDown` event:

```
procedure TForm1.VST1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then // only Abort if mouse left-button is pressed down
    abort;
end;
```